# CSS Animations of SVG images not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I need to animate images inside the svg. I am doing this with css3 animations. but somehow its not working in Internet Explorer. it is working fine in firefox and chrome.

css3 animations supported in internet explorer for svg images?

Below is my code:

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 2480 2480" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image class="animated fadeIn" width="2480" height="2480" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="/demo.Site/Media/Templates/1/digital/bg.png" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the website [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) to check if a browser supports a certain feature. Here you can see that SVG animations are indeed not supported on Internet Explorer: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20animation